# Dynamically creating canvas height for image display

Tags: reactjs

I am using the following code to dynamically create canvas height. But even though there is `onLoad`, console log for canvas height is 0.

`index.js`

```
import React, {useRef, useState, useEffect} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import background from "./background.png";

const Canvas = (props) => {
  const canvas = useRef(null);
  const image = useRef(null);  
  const [xLoc, setxLoc] = useState()
  const [yLocTop, setyLocTop] = useState()
  const [yLocBottom, setyLocBottom] = useState()
  const [canX, setCanX] = useState()
  const [canY, setCanY] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    const ctx = canvas.current.getContext("2d");
    image.current.onload = () => {
      ctx.drawImage(image.current, 0, 0);            
      ctx.font = "20px Courier";
      ctx.textAlign = "center";  
      ctx.fillText(props.textTop, xLoc, yLocTop);
      ctx.textAlign = "center";
      ctx.fillText(props.textBottom, xLoc, yLocBottom);
    };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const ctx = canvas.current.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(image.current, 0, 0);    
    ctx.font = "20px Courier";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText(props.textTop, xLoc, yLocTop);
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText(props.textBottom, xLoc, yLocBottom);
  });

  const handleOnLoad = e => {    
    console.log(e.target.offsetHeight)
    setCanX(e.target.offsetWidth)
    setCanY(e.target.offsetHeight)
    setxLoc(canX / 2);
    setyLocTop(canY * 0.87);
    setyLocBottom(canY * 0.13);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(canX)}
      {/* <canvas ref={canvas} width={canX || 0} height={canY || 0} /> */}
      <canvas ref={canvas} width="270" height="80" />
      <img 
        ref={image} 
        src={props.background} 
        onLoad={handleOnLoad} 
        hidden/>
    </div>
  );
};


function App() {  
  return (
    <div className="App">      
      <Canvas textTop="Top" textBottom="Bottom" background={background} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

The sandbox link is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-edison-g6ejc?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that if you set `<img hidden/>` then the image dimensions would simply be 0 height, 0 width.

You can still hide the image without using the hidden prop. Use a style that sets visibility to hidden, the image dimensions will be passed correctly. If you want to push `img` behind the canvas so that it will never be clicked. Use the following:

```
  <img
    ref={image}
    src={props.background}
    onLoad={handleOnLoad}
    style={{ visibility: "hidden", position: "absolute", top: "0", zIndex: "-1" }}
    alt=""
  />
```

See sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-wildflower-jov21

Additionally, you can workaround the `synchronous` behavior of your `handleLoad()` function. State-updating functions do not wait for other logic to complete before they execute. Before `setCanX` has time to complete, `setxLoc` is already running and in that case `canX` is still `undefined`. Which is why we get `NaN` when we try to divide `undefined` by 2. They do not wait like an `asynchronous` manner.

You should just pass in `event.target.offsetStuff` to the setter functions directly and it will work

```
 const handleOnLoad = e => {
    const { offsetHeight, offsetWidth } = e.target

    setCanX(offsetWidth);
    setCanY(offsetHeight);
    setxLoc(offsetWidth / 2);
    setyLocTop(offsetHeight * 0.87);
    setyLocBottom(offsetHeight * 0.13);
  };
```

Comment: Do you know why doesn't text show up? If you console log xLoc it is still Nan.

Comment: @Zanam really? I'm no longer getting NaN. I get the actual numbers now.

Comment: Yes in the second useEffect right before the curly bracket close add: console.log("asd");
    console.log(xLoc);

Comment: The problem is this:  `setCanX(e.target.offsetWidth);`  and  `setxLoc(canX / 2); `  The logic you have here is not synchronous. State-updating functions do not wait other logic to complete before they execute. Before setCanX has time to complete, setxLoc is already running and in that case canX is still undefined. Which is why we get NaN when we try to divide undefined by 2. You should just pass in event.target.offsetEtc to setxLoc directly and it will work :). See updated solution.

Comment: @Zanam just updated the sandbox too so you can see the fix

Comment: Love the explanation. Cleared my head. Thanks

Comment: @Zanam you're welcome friend, I'm glad that was helpful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are two `onload` functions for the image, one in the `useEffect()` and one in the property of the image. You can actually combine them and it'll work well. Here's the sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-platform-dc5wm).

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import background from "./background.png";

const Canvas = props => {
  const canvas = useRef(null);
  const image = useRef(null);
  const [xLoc, setxLoc] = useState();
  const [yLocTop, setyLocTop] = useState();
  const [yLocBottom, setyLocBottom] = useState();
  const [canX, setCanX] = useState();
  const [canY, setCanY] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const ctx = canvas.current.getContext("2d");
    image.current.onload = () => {
      ctx.drawImage(image.current, 0, 0);
      ctx.font = "20px Courier";
      ctx.textAlign = "center";
      ctx.fillText(props.textTop, xLoc, yLocTop);
      ctx.textAlign = "center";
      ctx.fillText(props.textBottom, xLoc, yLocBottom);

      setCanX(image.current.width);
      setCanY(image.current.height);
      setxLoc(canX / 2);
      setyLocTop(canY * 0.87);
      setyLocBottom(canY * 0.13);
    };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const ctx = canvas.current.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(image.current, 0, 0);
    ctx.font = "20px Courier";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText(props.textTop, xLoc, yLocTop);
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText(props.textBottom, xLoc, yLocBottom);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <canvas ref={canvas} width={canX || 0} height={canY || 0} />
      {/* <canvas ref={canvas} width="270" height="80" /> */}
      <img ref={image} src={props.background} hidden />
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Canvas textTop="Top" textBottom="Bottom" background={background} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: I don't think your answer works as when you console log the xLoc and yLocTop, they print Nan.